# lasagna plots: is there a way to delineate bars?

Tags: r

I am doing a lasagna plot that is very simple, it is for two options and two times, so there's not much subtlety in the graphics.

In the [github repository examples](https://github.com/swihart/lasagnar), when the lasagna plots print, there are black borders between the rows and columns:

[image: example lasagna plot from github]

However, when I reproduce it I don't have those borders:

```
library(devtools)                                                                                                                                
install_github("swihart/lasagnar")                                                               
library(fields)
library(lasagnar)   
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(colorspace)  
## get me a matrix with rownames:
mat <- matrix(1:100, nrow=10, ncol=10, byrow=TRUE)[sample(1:10),]
rownames(mat) <- letters[1:nrow(mat)]

lasagna(mat)
```

[image: Result when I run script above]

My question is, can I add in the boarders for my lasagna plots (and also can they be white?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the gridlines with the `gridlines=` argument. From `help(lasagna)`:

> gridlines   (logical) Add gridlines to the plot. Useful if image is not too big.

```
lasagna(mat,gridlines = TRUE)
```

[image]

As you can see from the [source code](https://github.com/swihart/lasagnar/blob/master/R/lasagna.R#L66), the color is hard coded:

```r
axis(1,seq( 1/(ncol(X)-1)*0.5, 1 - 1/(ncol(X)-1)*0.5, 
     length=(ncol(X)-1)),##c(1/10,3/10,5/10,7/10,9/10),
     labels=NA, tck=1, lty=1, col="black")
```

You can temporarily change the `lasagna` function with `trace(..., edit = TRUE)`:

```
trace(lasagna, edit=TRUE)
```

Manually edit the color to be white and add `col = "white"` to `box()`:

[image]

```
lasagna(mat,gridlines = TRUE) #with edited lasagna function
```

[image]